# iOS: Firebase invite through email not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-invites

I am trying to send the invitation through emails using Firebase. When i select the user and tap on send, i got an alert view saying invitation has been sent successfully. But i am not getting the email to the invitee.

Here is my code for sending the invite.

```
    // Invite friends
    id<FIRInviteBuilder> inviteDialog = [FIRInvites inviteDialog];
    [inviteDialog setInviteDelegate:self];




    FIRInvitesTargetApplication *targetApplication = [[FIRInvitesTargetApplication alloc] init];
    targetApplication.androidClientID = @"Android ID";
    [inviteDialog setOtherPlatformsTargetApplication:targetApplication];

    NSString *message =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Try this out!\n -%@",
    @"Ankur"];


    [inviteDialog setMessage:message];


    [inviteDialog setTitle:@"Invites Friends"];
    [inviteDialog setDeepLink:@"Deep_Link"];
    [inviteDialog setCallToActionText:@"Install!"];

    [inviteDialog open];
```

At the same time, i am getting the invitation if i send it through phone number.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is correct. Please check after sometime because it may take time to send email

Comment: I have already waited for a long time (1 day) still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your team ID in the firebase console, it is also required that you add an App Store id (it's ok to fake one for testing)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue because i have not mentioned the app store id in firebase console. After saving the AppStore ID, the issue got resolved.

Comment: I have everything set correctly on console, SHA, app id, team id... but I still have this issue :(